# How to get Colored cell with text from another sheet in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

How to get Colored cell with text from another sheet in google spreadsheet?

Hi, I have 2 sheets and I'm trying to get the colored cell with text from sheet 1 to sheet 2.

Can someone help me, please?

Example:

In sheet 1 i put a data in Column 1 Row 1 and then colored it
 with yellow at the same time it will appear in sheet 2 Column 1 Row 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Copy everything**

If you want to copy everything, including `Range` values, colour, background-colour, etc - use the simple `copyTo()` method. Just remember that `Range` dimensions should be equal (ofc, you can always add handling to account for that).

```
/**
 * Copies all;
 * @param {Range} source copy from range;
 * @param {Range} target copy to range;
 */
function copyAll(source,target) {
  source.copyTo(target);
}
```

**Conditional copy**

If you wish to copy only specific properties of the `Range`, the abovementioned `copyTo()` method can be invoked with `CopyPasteType` enum, like this (please, note that due to conflict with two-arg invocation `copyTo(range,options)`, transpose arg is necessary - you can hardcode it inside the function if you don't expect orientation changes):

```
/**
 * Copies only specific props;
 * @param {Range} source copy from range;
 * @param {Range} target copy to range;
 * @param {String} type enum CopyPasteType;
 * @param {Boolean} transposed change orientation or not;
 */
function copyConditional(source,target,type,transposed) {
  var t = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType[type];
  source.copyTo(target,t,transposed); //if transpose is not specified, will be treated as copyTo(destination,options)!;
}
```

**Copy via getter and setter**

For example, use the `getBackgrounds()` and `setBackgrounds()` respectively (there are a lot of other getter-setter methods you can use separately instead of the `copyTo()`, see `Range` reference in useful links).

```
/**
 * Copies background color;
 * @param {Range} source copy from range;
 * @param {Range} target copy to range;
 */
function copyColor(source,target) {
  var color = source.getBackgrounds();  
  target.setBackgrounds(color);
}
```

**Useful links**

1. `copyTo()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination);
2. `CopyPasteType` enum [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type);
3. `Range` class [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#methods);